# How do I visualize audio data?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, graphics, audio

I would like to have something that looks something like this. Two different colors are not nessesary.

[image: audacity on mac]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/images/audacity-macosx.png))</sub>

I already have the audio data (one sample/millisecond) from a stereo wav in two int arrays, one each for left and right channel. I have made a few attempts but they don't look anywhere near as clear as this, my attempts get to spikey or a compact lump.

Any good suggestions? I'm working in c# but psuedocode is ok.

Assume we have

- a function DrawLine(color, x1, y1, x2, y2)
- two int arrays with data right[]  and  left[] of lenght L
- data values between 32767 and -32768

If you make any other assumptions just write them down in your answer.

```
for(i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
  // What magic goes here?
}
```

This is how it turned out when I applied [the solution Han provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035533/how-do-i-visualize-audio-data/1036968#1036968). (only one channel)
[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1245877759099921200.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1245877759099921200.jpg)

Comment: Audacity is open source so you could look at the code. I'd assume something like the following...  func getHeight(v) { return abs(v) * 32767 / viewArea.height / 2); samplesPerPixelColumn = samples.len/viewArea.width; for i = 1 to viewArea.width {avgV = Avg(samples[i-i+samplesPerPixelColumn]); colHeight = getHeight(avgV); if  avgV >= 0 DrawLine(black, i, viewArea.height /2, i, (viewArea.height / 2) + colHeight) else DrawLine(black, i, viewArea.height /2, i, (viewArea.height / 2) - colHeight);  You'll probably need to do some rounding/range handling in there but that should be the gist.

Comment: Why don't you put that into an answer.

Comment: I wanted to give you something that might be immediately helpful but not get downvoted if part of it was off. More thoughts: Instead of vertical lines, draw diagonals between the previous graph point and next... Also, if you zoom in enough, you'll have multiple pixels per sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely have more than 1 sample for each pixel. For each group of samples mapped to a single pixel, you could draw a (vertical) line segment from the minimum value in the sample group to the maximum value. If you zoom in to 1 sample per pixel or less, this doesn't work anymore, and the 'nice' solution would be to display the sinc interpolated values.
Because DrawLine cannot paint a single pixel, there is a small problem when the minimum and maximum are the same. In that case you could copy a single pixel image in the desired position, as in the code below:

```
double samplesPerPixel = (double)L / _width;
double firstSample = 0;
int endSample = firstSample + L - 1;
for (short pixel = 0; pixel < _width; pixel++)
{
    int lastSample = __min(endSample, (int)(firstSample + samplesPerPixel));
    double Y = _data[channel][(int)firstSample];
    double minY = Y;
    double maxY = Y;
    for (int sample = (int)firstSample + 1; sample <= lastSample; sample++)
    {
        Y = _data[channel][sample];
        minY = __min(Y, minY);
        maxY = __max(Y, maxY);
    }
    x = pixel + _offsetx;
    y1 = Value2Pixel(minY);
    y2 = Value2Pixel(maxY);
    if (y1 == y2)
    {
        g->DrawImageUnscaled(bm, x, y1);
    }
    else
    {
        g->DrawLine(pen, x, y1, x, y2);
    }
    firstSample += samplesPerPixel;
}
```

Note that Value2Pixel scales a sample value to a pixel value (in the y-direction).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [R](http://www.r-project.org/) language for this.  I don't have very much experience with it, but it's used largely in statistical analysis/visualization scenarios.  I would be surprised if they didn't have some smoothing function to get rid of the extremes like you mentioned.

And you should have no trouble importing your data into it.  Not only can you read flat text files, but it's also designed to be easily extensible with C, so there is probably some kind of C# interface as well.

Comment: I doubt that calling an external application to draw my bitmaps would work. I'm updating the bitmap many times a second.