# How do I convert a stereo wav to mono

Tags: language-agnostic, audio

If I already have the wav data in two arrays (left channel & right channel) how does one go about to converting them to a single mono array?

Is there a function f so that **Mono[x] = f(L[x],R[x])** ?

Comment: If you don't have to do it very often, I would use Audacity.

Comment: Every time I import audio into my application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mixing is the average of the two channels.

```
f_mono = function(l, r) {  
   return (l + r) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: suppose you have a stereo file where there is a left-only sound and a center sound, which originally are perceived to have equal volume.  When you linearly add the two channels together, the center sound will instead be perceived as louder.  (Run the sound wave energy calculations with two point speakers and one mic, and then move the speakers together.)  I don't have any clever ideas as for how to avoid this, though.

Comment: It's not an issue thankfully. The audio is just a visual aid for timing issues. The original audio file is used when playing the ausdio. I just wanted to convert to mono to ease the calculation of the waveform. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035533/how-do-i-visualize-audio-data

Answer (score 4):

Just take an average of both value.